# What could be the cause of periodic "Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php'" for a WordPress site?

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress, php

My site works on WordPress.

Today it sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. The log is below.
Could you tell me whether this is the fault of the hoster?
I mean if the problem had something to do with the files of WordPress, the site couldn't work occasionally.

Anyway, what may be the possible reason of such behaviour?

```
[Thu Sep 15 00:14:13 2022] [error] [client 45.192.147.0:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
[Thu Sep 15 00:14:16 2022] [error] [client 192.198.126.151:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
[Thu Sep 15 00:14:17 2022] [error] [client 104.144.99.134:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:26 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:26 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/wordpress
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:26 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/Wordpress
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:27 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/WORDPRESS
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:27 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/WordPress
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:27 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/wp
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:27 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/Wp
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:28 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/WP
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:28 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/old
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:28 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/Old
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:29 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/OLD
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:29 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/oldsite
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:29 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/new
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:30 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/New
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:30 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/NEW
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:30 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/wp-old
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:30 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/2020
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:31 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/2019
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:31 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/2018
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:31 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/backup
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:32 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/test
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:32 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/Test
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:32 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/TEST
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:33 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/demo
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:33 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/bc
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:33 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/www
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:33 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/WWW
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:34 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/Www
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:34 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/2021
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:34 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/main
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:35 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/old-site
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:35 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/bk
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:35 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/Backup
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:36 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/BACKUP
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:36 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/SHOP
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:36 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/Shop
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:36 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/shop
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:37 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/bak
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:37 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/sitio
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:37 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/bac
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:38 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/sito
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:38 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/site
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:38 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/Site
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:39 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/SITE
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:39 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/blog
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:39 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/BLOG
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:39 2022] [error] [client 67.205.30.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/Blog
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:49 2022] [error] [client 82.118.29.216:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer https://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/vneshnetorgovyj-kontrakt/
[Thu Sep 15 00:41:49 2022] [error] [client 82.118.29.216:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer https://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/
[Thu Sep 15 00:55:41 2022] [error] [client 77.88.5.135:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 01:13:05 2022] [error] [client 216.131.114.205:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer https://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/vneshnetorgovyj-kontrakt/
[Thu Sep 15 01:13:05 2022] [error] [client 216.131.114.205:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer https://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/
[Thu Sep 15 01:31:46 2022] [error] [client 213.87.157.117:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer https://yandex.ru/
[Thu Sep 15 02:04:33 2022] [error] [client 66.249.66.30:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 02:26:03 2022] [error] [client 77.88.5.213:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 02:27:24 2022] [error] [client 178.67.184.114:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer https://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/vneshnetorgovyj-kontrakt/
[Thu Sep 15 02:27:25 2022] [error] [client 178.67.184.114:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer https://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/
[Thu Sep 15 03:06:07 2022] [error] [client 66.249.66.33:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:07:40 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.30:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:07:40 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.70:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:07:41 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.23:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:07:42 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.205:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:07:43 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.28:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:07:43 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.159:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:07:44 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.205:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:07:44 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.85:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:07:46 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.128:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:07:47 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.129:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:07:48 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.70:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:07:48 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.87:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:07:55 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.206:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:07:57 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:07:58 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.201:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:07:58 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.129:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:08:05 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.87:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:08:11 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:08:13 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.203:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:08:14 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:08:34 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.32:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:08:38 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.72:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:08:39 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.26:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:08:42 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.85:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:08:42 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.32:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:08:46 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.206:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:08:49 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.62:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:08:50 2022] [error] [client 66.249.92.32:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:09:58 2022] [error] [client 89.249.237.155:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer https://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/konverner-tnved-okpd/
[Thu Sep 15 03:09:58 2022] [error] [client 89.249.237.155:0] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required './wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php on line 22, referer https://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/konverner-tnved-okpd/
[Thu Sep 15 03:09:58 2022] [error] [client 89.249.237.155:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer https://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/konverner-tnved-okpd/
[Thu Sep 15 03:09:58 2022] [error] [client 89.249.237.155:0] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required './wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php on line 22, referer https://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/konverner-tnved-okpd/
[Thu Sep 15 03:09:58 2022] [error] [client 89.249.237.155:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer https://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/konverner-tnved-okpd/
[Thu Sep 15 03:09:58 2022] [error] [client 89.249.237.155:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer https://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/konverner-tnved-okpd/
[Thu Sep 15 03:12:57 2022] [error] [client 191.96.180.167:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer https://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/vneshnetorgovyj-kontrakt/
[Thu Sep 15 03:12:59 2022] [error] [client 191.96.180.167:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer https://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/
[Thu Sep 15 03:31:38 2022] [error] [client 147.78.47.249:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/_ignition/health-check/
[Thu Sep 15 03:31:41 2022] [error] [client 147.78.47.249:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/public/_ignition/health-check/
[Thu Sep 15 03:31:45 2022] [error] [client 147.78.47.249:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer http://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/wp-content/plugins/wp-file-manager/lib/php/connector.minimal.php
[Thu Sep 15 03:34:06 2022] [error] [client 66.249.66.28:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:41:49 2022] [error] [client 66.249.66.26:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:47:01 2022] [error] [client 195.19.217.163:0] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required './wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php on line 22, referer https://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/konverner-tnved-okpd/
[Thu Sep 15 03:54:01 2022] [error] [client 152.89.196.13:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:57:29 2022] [error] [client 152.89.196.13:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:58:02 2022] [error] [client 79.104.222.173:0] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required './wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php on line 22, referer https://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/konverner-tnved-okpd/
[Thu Sep 15 03:58:02 2022] [error] [client 79.104.222.173:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17, referer https://xn--b1ae8e.xn--p1ai/konverner-tnved-okpd/
[Thu Sep 15 03:59:46 2022] [error] [client 151.55.27.89:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
[Thu Sep 15 03:59:46 2022] [error] [client 151.55.27.89:0] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '__DIR__/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/g/grablmz2/ved.rf/public_html/index.php on line 17
```

Comment: Depends on who is managing the WordPress installation, you or the hoster? From just this log I would say there is a fatal error in the WordPress installation or one of the plugin used, and that needs to be solved.

Comment: Who is your host? If it's someone reputable, like BlueHost or DreamHost or HostGator or WPEngine, you can call customer support and let them run some diagnostics. I've done this for clients before and these web hosting companies were very helpful. Otherwise, as Patrick alluded, see if you can update your WP version or turn your plugins off one by one and see if you can isolate the issue.

Comment: In the WordPress dashboard > updates, there is an option to re-install WP.  That would be the first thing I would try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is likely to be a webserver issue.   It could be that there are limits and they don't have enough file-descriptors (but I've not seen that before) but **more likely there is some corruption with the filesystem**, or maybe the file is on a shared network and is intermittently unreachable - unlikely because I'd expect there to be more errors then just the 1 then.

The problem does not look like an issue with the version of WP or a plugin to me.  The problem is clearly an issue thrown up by PHP looking for a standard Wordpress file - using standard access means - which should exist on disk is not being found by the OS (or at least its not being found by PHP).

It is conceivable that there is some back end replication/distribution of files happening, and a cluster of machines, some of which can access the file, some of which can't.

Certainly reinstalling Wordpress (or even just deleting and re-adding wp-blog-header.php) has a decent chance of fixing the problem - although I would definately do backups, because if its a filesystem corruption things could get messy.